# I wanna make apk for react native app and there is an error Gradle build failed with unknown error

Tags: react-native, gradle-plugin, gradlew, gradle-wrapper, react-native-blur

```
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:[0.32,)'
```

I tried to do this but got the same error:

[image: error]

and I update all required dependences and still same error and  can't solve it so my some soultions if  any one face same error

Comment: Did you start a new project ? If you can create a new project use ```npx react-native@latest init MyProject```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace   `implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:[0.32,)'` with `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`